# Are there any open source CCG projects?

Tags: open-source, card-game

I'm having trouble finding any well-developed open source Collectible Card Game projects.

I want to find projects to learn from and port to a mobile platform.

Comment: I imagine some of your difficulty may be related to the WOTC patent on the core mechanics of most collectible card games.

Comment: Noctrine: how do you reconcile that with not just the continuing plethora of CCGs to be released in physical form, but the swath of digital CCGs like Alteil?  I don't believe _all_ of them are licensing the WOTC patents...

Comment: @Steven, That is why I said most. I am sure most of them aren't licensing WOTC (either because they aren't infringing or they are to small for them to be bothered with) I just know that every time I have seen anything get reasonably popular in that space I hear about litigation from WOTC.

Comment: @Steven, Ultimately though, it was wild guessing on my part. That's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Why is this question off-topic to gamedev Stack Exchange? It isn't about "how to get started," "what to learn next," or "which technology to use". Is there a Stack Exchange site better suited fir that kind of question?

I would like to figure out if there are other genuine open source CCG projects except for WTactics.

Answer (score 7):

I'm one of the devs behind [WTactics.org](http://WTactics.org) and would of course recommend our project over Forge as it's open, while the other is written to play Magic: The gathering against an A.I.

Art wise we have plenty and more to come since we hire artist(s). Code wise we have plenty of things cooking, like for example local client, a browser based version and card also online development tools.

Personally I wouldn't ever recommend anyone to play a CCG on a small mobile device, but I guess that's just my own preferences.

Anyways, a safe bet would be Wagic, if you, again, don't care much about it being a MtG centric AI. The good thing with it is that it even runs on a PSP, which I think is already more mobile than *perhaps* Forge is.

Answer (score 4):

http://wtactics.org/ Has nice card art assets already

Answer (score 3):

I've found nice one - [Forge card game](http://www.slightlymagic.net/wiki/Forge)

Comment: That project is closed.